# Using Spark ML Pipelines just for Transformations

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am working on a project where configurable pipelines and lineage tracking of alterations to Spark DataFrames are both essential. The endpoints of this pipeline are usually just modified DataFrames (think of it as an ETL task). What made the most sense to me was to leverage the already existing Spark ML Pipeline API to track these alterations. In particular, the alterations (adding columns based on others, etc.) are implemented as custom Spark ML Transformers.

However, we are now having an internal about debate whether or not this is the most idiomatic way of implementing this pipeline. The other option would be to implement these transformations as series of UDFs and to build our own lineage tracking based on a DataFrame's schema history (or Spark's internal DF lineage tracking). The argument for this side is that Spark's ML pipelines are not intended just ETL jobs, and should always be implemented with goal of producing a column which can be fed to a Spark ML Evaluator. The argument against this side is that it requires a lot of work that mirrors already existing functionality.

Is there any problem with leveraging Spark's ML Pipelines strictly for ETL tasks? Tasks that only make use of Transformers and don't include Evaluators?

Answer (score 1):

For me, seems like a great idea, especially if you can compose the different Pipelines generated into new ones since a Pipeline can itself be made of different pipelines since a Pipeline extends from PipelineStage up the tree (source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline).

But keep in mind that you will probably being doing the same thing under the hood as explained here (https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-mllib/spark-mllib-transformers.html):

> Internally, transform method uses Spark SQL’s udf to define a function (based on createTransformFunc function described above) that will create the new output column (with appropriate outputDataType). The UDF is later applied to the input column of the input DataFrame and the result becomes the output column (using DataFrame.withColumn method).

If you have decided for other approach or found a better way, please, comment. It's nice to share knowledge about Spark.