# Convert spark pipeline to dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pipeline, databricks

The Spark Pipeline framework allows for creation of pipelines of transforms for machine learning or other applications in a reproducible way. However, when creating the dataframes, I want to be able to perform exploratory analysis.

In my case, I have ~100 columns, of which 80 are strings and need to be one hot encoded:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoderEstimator, StringIndexer,VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegressionModel

#cols_to_one_hot_encode_2 is a list of columns that need to be one hot encoded
#cols_to_keep_as_is are columns that are **note** one hot encoded

cols_to_one_hot_encode_3=[i+"_hot" for i in cols_to_one_hot_encode_2]
encoder= OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=cols_to_one_hot_encode_2,
                                 outputCols=cols_to_one_hot_encode_3,dropLast=False)

#assemble pipeline
vectorAssembler = VectorAssembler().setInputCols(cols_to_keep_as_is+cols_to_one_hot_encode_3).setOutputCol("features")
all_stages=indexers
all_stages.append(encoder)
all_stages.append(vectorAssembler)
transformationPipeline=Pipeline(stages=all_stages)
fittedPipeline=transformationPipeline.fit(df_3)
dataset = fittedPipeline.transform(df_3)

#now pass to logistic regression
selectedcols = ["response_variable","features"] #+df_3.columns
dataset_2= dataset.select(selectedcols)

# Create initial LogisticRegression model
lr = LogisticRegression(labelCol="response_variable", featuresCol="features", maxIter=10,elasticNetParam=1)

# Train model with Training Data
lrModel = lr.fit(dataset_2)
```

When I look at dataset_2 `display(dataset_2)`, it prints:

```
response_variable       features
0   [0,6508,[1,4,53,155,166,186,205,242,2104,6225,6498],[8220,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
0   [0,6508,[1,3,53,155,165,185,207,243,2104,6225,6498],[8220,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
0   [0,6508,[1,2,53,158,170,185,206,241,2104,6225,6498],[8222,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
0   [0,6508,[1,3,53,156,168,185,205,240,2104,6225,6498],[8222,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
0   [0,6508,[1,2,53,155,166,185,205,240,2104,6225,6498],[8223,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

Which is totally useless for doing feature exploration.Notice that the one-hot encoder has exploded my features from ~100 columns to 6508.

**My question**

How do I look at the dataframe that iscreated under the hood by the pipeline?
This should be a dataframe that has 6058 features and the corresponding number of rows, such as:
 For example, I want something like:

```
response_variable    feature_1_hot_1 feature_1_hot_2  feature_1_hot_3 ... (6505 more columns)
0                    1               1                0

etc.
```

**Not a duplicate**

Not a duplicate of [How to split Vector into columns - using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark) 
That is asking how to do literal string splitting based on a delimiter. The transform done by the pipeline is not a simple string splitting. See [Using Spark ML Pipelines just for Transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820188/using-spark-ml-pipelines-just-for-transformations)

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split Vector into columns - using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark)

Comment: modifed to explain why not duplicate

Answer (score 1):

> How do I look at the dataframe that iscreated under the hood by the pipeline?

There is no such hidden structure. Spark ML `Pipelines` are build around `VectorUDT` columns and metadata to enrich the structure. There is no intermediate structure that holds expanded columns, and if there where, it wouldn't scale (Spark doesn't handle wide and dense data that would be generated here, and query planner chokes when number of columns gets into tens of thousands) given the current implementation.

[Splitting the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384347/how-to-split-vector-into-columns-using-pyspark) and [analyzing the metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42935914/) is your best and only option.

Comment: So there is no method to create such a dataframe? I find that very hard to believe.